# Is it possible to fire FB.login function without opening any popup (so that I log existing users)?

Tags: facebook

My idea is to fire the FB.Login function automatically and if the user has already granted permissions to my app I log him in, if he hasn't I don't want the function to open the Login with Facebook popup.

I want to do this to authenticate users directly when they get to my "login" page so that they don't have to click "Login with Facebook". If the user hasn't granted permissions yet, he stays in the page and has the option to click "Login with Facebook".

Basically I want to run the FB.login function but prevent it from opening the popup. This would log the user only if he doesn't need to grant permissions. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean already logged in user? What does mean by 'if the user has already granted permissions to my app I log him in'?

Comment: Maybe `FB.getLoginStatus` is already able to solve your problem?

Comment: No, I don't mean already logged users. I mean users that have already connected to the app before but have not authenticated. I want to run the FB.login function while preventing it from opening popups so that I only log users that have already connected with the app before.